# Mixed clustering (Kmeans + Hierarchical) in Weka?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, hierarchical-clustering

is it possible to do mixed clustering in `Weka Knowledge Flow` ? so we can redirect the output of K-means algorithm to the input of the hierarchical clustering ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? Clusters of clusters? Both are rather crude heuristics, so why apply one heuristic to another heuristic? You usually don't feed a support vector machine into a decision tree either, do you?!?

Comment: I read that we can do this kind of clustering, k-kmeans will provide a maximum number of clusters, then hierarchical will help to determinate the optimum number by joining adjacent clusters. This method has an implementation under R: http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/multidim/html/mixte.html

Comment: Probably just hierarchical clustering applied to the *means*. But again, just yet another heuristic applied to a heuristic.